# Determining if this is an orthonormal set.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

$p(x)\:=\:a+ax+ax^2$ and
$q(x)\:=\:b+bx+bx^2$ are vectors in $P_2$

The inner product is the dot product:
$$\langle p,q\rangle=a_0b_0+a_1b_1+a_2b_2$$

the set is:

$$\left\{\left(\frac{3x^2+4x}{5}\right),\:\left(\frac{-4x^2+3x}{5}\right),\:1\right\}$$

So I have to determine if this thing an orthonormal set.

after computing the magnitude to see if it equals 1, I ended up with
the magnitude equaling $\frac{25}{25}x^4+\frac{25}{25}x^2+1$

I compared this question's answer to a similar one in the back of the textbook and it was in the same format as this one.

Does this answer makes the set orthonormal or not?

Comment: Read your definition of the inner product again. Your norms and inner products should have no powers of $x$ in them. To check if the set is orthonormal you need to show that (a) the inner product of every pair of vectors in the set is zero (b) the norm of every vector in the set is 1.

Comment: The definition of your inner product is just **on the coefficients**, without the $\;x$'s ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have three vectors $$(0,4/5,3/5)^T, (0, 3/5, -4/5)^T, (1, 0, 0)^T $$ with the usual inner product. each of them have length $1$ and they are mutually orthogonal, therefore they form an orthonormal basis for $P_2.$

Comment: ok, I can see now.